# How to install JRE-7 on Xubuntu?

Tags: java, oracle, jre

I have followed the other question and did not succeed.

`mv: cannot move './jre1.7.0_04' to '/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0': No such file or directory`

Is it installed into the 32bit compatible /lib directory only?

running:
Linux user 2.6.38-14-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP time-date-stuff x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Xubuntu does not include any java (yeah!), but now I want to play with yED. :(

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't exist, create it:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv ./jre1.7.0_04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore you have to select JRE-7 as your new java runtime environment:

[Take therefore a look at this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)